# problem while updating or upgrading

Tags: updates

When I try to run `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get the following error:

```
:urphoton@nur-pc:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcgmanager0:i386 linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 152 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
debconf: Perl may be unconfigured (Can't locate IO/File.pm in @INC (you may need to install the IO::File module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/share/perl/5.18/FileHandle.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 1) line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 3.
) -- aborting
(Reading database ... 932190 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic (3.13.0-39.66) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/block/paride/pf.ko': Not a directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What command did you run before that? Did you try to install/remove anything from the system? Did you run `sudo apt-get autoremove` ?

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure perl`.

Comment: @ bhordupur: I tried to install What exactly I do not remember and also I think that The command sudo apt-get autoremove  was run

Comment: @Zacharee1  its not working

Comment: can you run this command `sudo software-properties-gtk` ? Click on **Ubuntu Software** and check  them all.

Comment: @bhordupur : I run this command and check , next is what?

Comment: try to run ‘sudo apt-get update‘ and ‘sudo apt-get upgrade ‘

Comment: @bhordupur again there is problem last few lines of outcome       
) -- aborting
(Reading database ... 932190 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic (3.13.0-39.66) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/block/paride/pf.ko': Not a directory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1

Comment: run `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo apt-get  clean` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get update` .If there is still problem exist then comment here and tell us what version of ubuntu you are running to see that run `lsb_release -a`

Comment: first command Showing this- subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic
I am using 14.04.4

Comment: I would say to upgrade the kernel to 4.4 .Hopefully it might fix your problem.